# Implement Modal Popup or redirection on single button in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have button in my blade View. What i wish is onclick, I want let the verified users to go to dashboard otherwise open a Modal Popup and ask them to register or login first.

I've created a popup modal with dummy data that works fine for guest users but don't know the logic or code for verified users to let them navigate to their dashboard page. 
Any suggestion please.

Blade

```
<main id="main">
@section('content')

  <!-- Page Content -->
  <section class="py-5 product_1">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="align-self-center mx-auto text-center py-5">

           <a href="" class="buy-button"><span>Generate  A Dynamic QR CODE for Sellers</span></a>
      </div>

      <!-- Button trigger modal -->
      <button type="button" class="btn buy-button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
        Generate Security
      </button>

      @guest

      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
@endguest

      <script>window.location = "/dashboard";</script>

    </div>
  </section>
@endsection
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

You used `@guest` and `@endguest` there's also `@auth` and `@endauth` for when you have a logged in user.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback but If you could explain it a little bit more that could be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself.

I created 2 buttons. 
I wrapped one button into @guest and the other one into @auth and it worked for me.

```
  @guest
      <!-- Button trigger modal -->

  <button type="button" class="buy-button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModel">
          Generate Security
  </button>

  @endguest
```

and

```
@auth

    <button type="button" class="buy-button" 
    onclick="window.location='{{route('createCode',['code'=> 'dashboard']) }}';" >

    Generate Security

    </button>

    @endauth
```

Comment: I wouldn't have been able to write you code for you, but that's exactly where I was trying to get you to go, great.

Comment: @Azeame I just posed my another problem. Could you please help me here. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61186615/how-to-prevent-guest-user-to-access-verified-page