# How to prevent guest user to access verified page

Tags: php, laravel

I've a button in my blade View that is only accessible for authenticated users. On button click, verified users are redirected to a new page named **qrcode**. Now I want to restrict guest users to access this page directly.

I defined a middleware but that's not working for this page. Why is this?

My page **qrcode.blade.php** is located in **Views/Auth** folder.

**Views/Products/Blade.php**

```
@auth
  <button type="button" class="buy-button" onclick="window.location='{{route('firstProductQR',['firstQR' => 'qrcode']) }}'" >
      Generate Dynamic QR  </button>
@endauth
```

**Route.php**

```
Route::group([ 'middleware' => ['web']], function(){

  Route::get('/',[

    'uses' => 'niceActionController@getActionController'
  ]);

Route::get('/{firstQR}' , [
  'middleware' => 'auth',
  'uses' => 'niceActionController@getFirstProductQrPage',
  'as'=> 'firstProductQR'
]);


});/*End Web Middleware*/
```

**niceActionController.php**

```
class niceActionController extends Controller
{

public function getFirstProductQrPage($firstQR)
{
  return view($firstQR);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* ROUTES */

Route::get('/QR/{firstQR}' , [
  'uses' => 'niceActionController@getFirstProductQrPage',
  'as'=> 'firstProductQR'
]);

*/


use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth; // important..
    class niceActionController extends Controller
    {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:web'); // use this only to make this whole controller accessible to only logged users.
    }

    public function getFirstProductQrPage($firstQR)
    {
      // or use this only for this function.
      // Auth::user()->id will check if the user is logged in & have an user ID, if not found it will goes to else...
      if(Auth::user()->id)
      {
        return view($firstQR);
      } else {
       return redirect('/home');
      }

    }

    }
```

Comment: I can't define middleware for complete controller as other webpages are accessible through this controller.

Anyways, I used your second piece of code, still I' m accessing "qrcode" page..

Comment: are you sure you have logged out ??

because the code is absolutely correct.

Comment: okk, have you used the Auth Facades ??

if not then add


use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

Comment: just added into my controller " use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;".. Nothing happened :( .. 
i even clear my cache using composer dump-autoload. Still same problem

Comment: Surprising thing is,  Under Views/Auth folder, only this one page is not accepting middleware. Other are working fine

Comment: try one more this..

replace
`Auth::user()->id`

to 


`Auth::guard('web')->id()`

Comment: I' m not understanding why only this page not accepting middleware .. It's weird ......... :(